# Tp-link tl-wn722n v3 modo monitor

Tags: wireless, usb, hacking

estuve mirando en Youtube tutoriales, entré a muchos lugares que no supieron resolver mí problema, es más, instalando un drivers que vi en Youtube hizo que mí Ubuntu se cuelgue cada vez que conectaba mí USB wifi, así que tuve que volver a instalar el sistema operativo.
¿Algún consejo para ponerlo en modo monitor?
¿Algún drivers? O algo por favor y gracias.

From Google Translater:

I was looking at YouTube tutorials, I went to many places that did not know how to solve my problem, moreover, installing a driver that I saw on YouTube made my Ubuntu crash every time I connected my USB wifi, so I had to reinstall the system operative Any advice to put it in monitor mode? Any drivers? Or something please and thank you.